# install rcssserver

Tags: ubuntu, make

I'm trying to install rcssserver on Ubuntu 14.04.5, after ./configure I write the command "sudo make" and I get a bunch of lines of description and error. I can someone give me a clue on how to install it? Thanks in advance

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
Making all in libltdl
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
Making all in rcssbase
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase'
Making all in error
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/error'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/error'
Making all in lib
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../libltdl  -I/usr/include -W -I./src -g -O2 -MT loader.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/loader.Tpo -c -o loader.lo loader.cpp
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../libltdl -I/usr/include -W -I./src -g -O2 -MT loader.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/loader.Tpo -c loader.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/loader.o
loader.cpp: In static member function ‘static boost::filesystem::path rcss::lib::Loader::stripDirName(const boost::filesystem::path&)’:
loader.cpp:158:38: error: conversion from ‘boost::filesystem::path’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested
     std::string rval = filename.leaf();
                                      ^
make[4]: *** [loader.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Crossposted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057806/install-rcssserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnurubuntu/rubuntu sudo apt-get update
```

This will automatically add an entry to your source list based on your Ubuntu version.

Install the server and monitor:

```
sudo apt-get install rcssserver rcssmonitor
```